# Tint on an image button swift Xcode

Tags: swift, uibutton, tint

I want to add 35% transparent tint on a button with image in my Xcode project.Suggest me how to do it in my case

My Code:

```
// Button
        let aButt = UIButton(type: .custom)
        aButt.frame = CGRect(x: X, y: Y, width: W, height: H)
        aButt.tag = i
        aButt.setTitle("\(peObj[EVENTS_TITLE]!)", for: .normal)
        aButt.contentVerticalAlignment = .bottom
        aButt.titleLabel?.font = UIFont(name: "OpenSans-Bold", size: 13)
        aButt.setTitleColor(UIColor.white, for: .normal)
        aButt.addTarget(self, action: #selector(popularEventButt(_:)), for: .touchUpInside)
        getParseImage(object: peObj, colName: EVENTS_IMAGE1, button: aButt)
        aButt.imageView?.contentMode = .scaleAspectFill
        aButt.clipsToBounds = true
        aButt.backgroundColor = UIColor.lightGray
        aButt.layer.cornerRadius = 8
```

Comment: What is _add 35% tint on a button_? Can you show an example of what you are trying to achieve?

Comment: Documentation shows there's a [`tint`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uibutton) property on UIButton that is a `UIColor`. While I'm not sure what you mean by a 35% tint, you can add an alpha component to the color by adding `.withAlphaComponent(0.35)` after your color.